# How to get the PowerShell version from all EC2 instances running on the aws account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, fleet

In our company we have hundreds of instances, some Linux and some Windows. I need to check what instances need to have the latest PowerShell installed, therefore I need a list of PowerShell versions for all the instances.

In order to get the information, I was thinking of somehow using the fleet manager (from system manager) to gather this information about all the instances, but not sure how to do it.

Would appreciate any advice.

Comment: See this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zUQUpmMgqDQ  It will help to solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for it: run command with systems manager is the answer. Use it with the RunPowerShellScript document, have it ask each instance for their $psversiontable.psversion, and dump it into s3 for easier querying